# Representing axis values to the power of 3

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to see in my axis values of

```
24^3 48^3 92^3
```

however my file only have single values

```
24
48
92
```

How can I set these values?
I have tried

```
%T  power to base 10
%L  power to base of current logscale
%S  scientific power
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a terminal that can be enhanced (for example, set terminal qt|png|postscript eps enhanced). Then add a command like

set format x "%g^{3}"

Comment: @_Michael O. Thanks. That helps. Not the prettiest representation of power of 3, but helps.